# MKPolylines-routeLines not showing in my MKMapView, but everything is correct?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, polyline, mkoverlay, mkpolyline

I am new to this so it may be that I'm missing something simple or whatever else.

Basically I want to draw a straight line from point to point, in my case I have all of my points in which each line should be drawn in an array of coordinates. And then I use overlay method to draw the line. And all of this in a MKMapView which I already defined and configured (Correctly).

So here is the code that I use to fill my array of coordinates and also create the overlay/polyline:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateArray[arrayOfLatitudes.count];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfLatitudes.count; i++) {

    double tempLatitude = [[arrayOfLatitudes objectAtIndex:(i)] doubleValue];
    double tempLongitude = [[arrayOfLongitudes objectAtIndex:(i)] doubleValue];

    coordinateArray[i] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(tempLatitude, tempLongitude);


}

self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinateArray count:arrayOfLatitudes.count];
[self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:[self.routeLine boundingMapRect]]; //If you want the route to be visible
[self.mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];
```

and this is my ViewForOverlay method which I asume configures my routeLine:

```
(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
 if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]])
 {
    MKPolylineView *mapOverlayView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
    //add autorelease if not using ARC
    mapOverlayView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
    mapOverlayView.lineWidth = 3;
    return mapOverlayView;
}

return nil;
```

}

I have these declarations in my .h as well:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MKPolyline *routeLine; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) MKPolylineView *routeLineView;
```

I don't know why I can't see my routeLine drawn in my MapView, because I have used the exact logic(order of things) in another class and the lines appear with no problem.

What am I missing here? please help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention,The first block of code is inside a method called "waitForMe" (void). Im calling waitForMe from my viewDidLoad method.